# Memory leak when using Torch and Torchvision in conjunction with XGBoost

Tags: python, pytorch, xgboost

Please help to fix or investigate an issue in one of the services I work on, where it would use more and more memory until crashing. After some digging around I was able to reduce it to the following script:

```
import argparse
import logging
import math
import os

import psutil
import torch
import torchvision
import xgboost

import numpy as np


def main() -> None:
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("xgboost_model_path")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    feature_extractor = torchvision.models.vit_b_16(num_classes=512)

    predictor = xgboost.XGBClassifier(
        base_score=0.5,
        booster=None,
        colsample_bylevel=1,
        colsample_bynode=1,
        colsample_bytree=1,
        gamma=0,
        gpu_id=-1,
        importance_type="gain",
        interaction_constraints=None,
        learning_rate=0.3,
        max_delta_step=0,
        max_depth=10,
        min_child_weight=1,
        missing=math.nan,
        monotone_constraints=None,
        n_estimators=300,
        n_jobs=32,
        num_parallel_tree=1,
        objective="multi:softprob",
        random_state=0,
        reg_alpha=0,
        reg_lambda=1,
        scale_pos_weight=None,
        subsample=1,
        tree_method=None,
        validate_parameters=False,
        verbosity=0,
    )
    predictor.load_model(args.xgboost_model_path)

    frames_torch = torch.rand((1, 3, 224, 224), device="cpu")
    i = 0
    while True:
        with torch.no_grad():
            embedding = feature_extractor(frames_torch).numpy().mean(axis=0)
        if i == 0:
            logging.warning(f"Mem usage (embedding) {process.memory_percent()}")
        features = np.expand_dims(embedding, 0)
        predictor.predict_proba(features)
        i = (i + 1) % 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I left this script running for a day and memory usage grew from 640MB to about 9GB. This issue seems to depend on the import order, if XGBoost is imported before torch and torch-vision the memory usage is more or less constant (I didn't leave it to run for the same amount of time but I didn't see an upwards trend that's clearly visible otherwise).

I use xgboost==1.7.5
I don't know if this is an issue with XGBoost specifically, but hopefully, someone here has ideas on what could be the cause. I suspect that this might be related to some library that both Torch and XGBoost use, like OpenMP.

Other versions:
PyTorch version: 2.0.1+cu117
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.7
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (x86_64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.26.4
Libc version: glibc-2.31

Python version: 3.9.15 (main, Jun 12 2023, 04:04:50)  [GCC 9.4.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-5.15.0-1036-aws-x86_64-with-glibc2.31
Is CUDA available: True
CUDA runtime version: 11.3.58
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: LAZY